# How to run the content script when the YouTube site is navigated in 2022?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I'm making a simple Chrome extension for YouTube. I've succeeded at that, but my script only works after refreshing a page. YouTube site doesn't reload pages on navigation. The extension's content scripts aren't reinjected when URL changes without a page being reloaded. Naturally when I reload a page manually the content script is executed.

How to run the content script when the site is navigated?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

    function injectScript() {
       
      if(document.querySelector('#a') === null && document.querySelector('#player.style-scope') !== null){
        
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#player')).pop().insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", `<div id="a" style="color:red">Code</div>`);

        // Code

      }
    }

    const  element = document.querySelector('body');

    function childList(list){
      injectScript();
    }

    let callback = function(mutations, observer) {
      mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if(mutation.type === 'childList'){
          childList(mutation);
        }
      });
    }

    const mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback);

    const config = {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    };
    mutationObserver.observe(element, config);

})
```

Comment: I think you will need to use a browser extension that runs code on page load. Like [tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/?ext=dhdg&browser=chrome).

Comment: How does this help solve the problem?

Comment: I don't think `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ `is necessary.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what does your question have to do with the year 2022?